# inotify API with select

Tags: c, linux, select, inotify

I am trying to use inotify with a select() call.

The time_out is set at 3 secs. I cannot seem to get it to work.

The select always returns zero.

Code snippet,

```
    fd_set fds;

    //fd is descriptor for inotify_init
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(fd, &fds);

    struct timeval time_wait;
    while(true)
    {
            time_wait.tv_sec=3;
            time_wait.tv_usec=0;
            i = 0;
            res = select(fd , &fds, NULL, NULL, &time_wait);

            if (ret == -1) {
                    printf("Error occured in inotify read \n");
                    break;
            }

            if(ret == 0) {         
                    //always triggers
                    printf("timed out \n");
                    continue;
            }

            //Never reaches here
            printf("Event occured \n");
            ......
    }
```

If I do not use select, it works fine. And it also works well with poll().

I also tried inotify_init1() with IN_NONBLOCK

Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the first argument to [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) is the highest descriptor in any set *plus one*. So in your case it should be `fd + 1`.

Secondly, the `select` function *modifies* the sets, so you need to add the descriptors every iteration in the loop.

Comment: I forgot to add the +1 when I pasted here. 
Yup, problem was with select() modifying the sets.